# Where is the 'req' parameter defined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement an authentication scheme described [here](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8).

I'm struggling to find where the `req` parameter is defined in the code below. My code would not compile as it is not currently defined. This could be a typo in his code. I looked through the comments but nobody seems to have pointed that out:

```
// src/app/auth/jwt.interceptor.ts
// ...
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // do stuff with response if you want
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          // redirect to the login route
          // or show a modal
        }
      }
    });
  }
}"
```

Can someone point out what i'm missing?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a type of `request`.

Comment: Probably a typo of `request`

Comment: I'm new to javascript/Typescript/angular but now understand why nobody cared to comment on this. It would have to be request. many thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo to me. The intercept function provides a parameter `request` - it should probably be referring to that instead of `req`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter must read as `request` as below

```
return next.handle(request)
        .do(event => {
            if ()
```